# Sunspot facet query with exclude option and any_of fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot, facet, sunspot-solr

After researching for a good amount of time, finally writing this.

I am doing a solr query to find all the records that have specific `object_id` and also another field which tells `active/inactive`. And then need to get the counts that are `active` and as well as `total count` (that includes **active/inactive** and also belongs to specified **object_ids**)

```
Model.search() do
  with(:object_id, params[:ids])
  active_condition = with(:active, true)
  facet(:object_id, exclude: active_condition)
end
```

This is returning all the records. But, the requirement is to fetch the count that are belongs to only specific **object_ids** and also both **active/inactive**.

Is it possible to get the counts with this approach ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to facet on the `active` field instead:

```
Model.search() do
  with(:object_id, params[:ids])
  active_condition = with(:active, true)

  facet(:active, exclude: active_condition)
end
```

This returns the active and inactive counts of the object_ids you scoped on.

Comment: Thanks a million @fivedigit. Worked like a charm.